# edit a textarea in jquery popup box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popupwindow

I have a div in which contents are displayed in ordered list with a checkbox for each. these are displayed by fetching from the database. now i need to display the content near to the selected check box. what i did so far is

```
1) only one check box can be selected at a time

2) get the id of the check box which is selected stored to variable ids

3) then paragraph content id = "p"+checkbox id
```

The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':checkbox').bind('change', function() {
        var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $(':checkbox.' + thisClass + ":not(#" + this.id + ")").removeAttr('checked');
        }

    });
});

function edit_temp(prt){
        var checkedAtLeastOne = false;

            $('input[name="check_clinic"]').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                       checkedAtLeastOne = true;
                       ids = $(this).attr('id');
                        }
                    });
                    if(checkedAtLeastOne){
                         p_id ="p"+ids;
                      alert(p_id);
                       }
                    else{
                          alert('Please select any clinical Interpretation');
                    }
        }
```

So far this is working perfectly. but now i need to display the content of the `<p>` tag with id `p_id` in a text area inside a popup window. and then edit the text and by clicking the update button of popup box that content must be updated in db.

can anyone help me to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a php file that will receive the row id from database and prints it to textarea in a form. and when user clicks submit the form action will update the db. Here are the step by step guide what you need to do:

1. Add an "a" tag which opens popup.php?id=1 (where 1 is the id of the row)
2. Create the popup.php file, which fetch record from database
3. Add a form element with textarea and submit button in popup.php and populate your textarea with the value fetched in step 2
4. Either create a new file called update.php or check if the page has post request in popup php and update the value in db with the given id and textarea value.

Hope this will help you to finish.

Comment: If you want a "modal" box i suggest you to use fancybox (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) or colorbox will do the trick (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) . When you say popup, i thought you will use window.open function to open an actual popup. But modal box will do the same too.